How can I restore visibility/access to my sitemaps from GSC? Getting 500 Error
I'm bulk deleting old sitemaps from a domain property (approximately 30,000) from GSC using OAuth 2.0 Playground via Windows Command Prompt. After each batch of 1000, I would check GSC to ensure successful deletions. After about 10,000, I clicked on Sitemaps (to verify deletions as previously mentioned) and got a generic 500 error.
I've tried waiting, sending a message via "feedback" on the console, and removing the property and re-adding it and still get the same error. It's been a couple weeks now so after extensive research, it doesn't seem to be Google server error related as I imagine it would've been fixed by now. Anyone experience anything like this?
